# How to force remove phpmyadmin with `sudo`?

Tags: 14.04, root, phpmyadmin

I have been trying to uninstall phpmyadmin using:

```
sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin*
```

However, during that process, I'm getting errors and it is not being removed. I assume I have mixed up the ubuntu root password and the phpmyadmin root password or something. I definitely know my `sudo` root password however. Below is the error I'm getting:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 265659 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing phpmyadmin (4:4.0.10-1) ...
dbconfig-common: dumping mysql database phpmyadmin to /var/tmp/phpmyadmin.phpmyadmin.2015-07-29-21.04.mysql.Asn2CB.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).
unable to connect to mysql server.
error encountered dumping database:
```

Comment: What? VBoxGuestAdditions on VirtualBox and phpmyadmin? Very confusing.

Comment: Whoops sorry - totally wrong title there! Title is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your MySQL server is running. Check the password for your MySQL user `root` and the access rights for this user in the `mysql.user` table. Do this in a terminal with the `mysql` command.

If that's not possible, run

```
sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin*
```

again and answer the question

```
   ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤ Configuring phpmyadmin ├────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
   │                                                                                                                                  │ 
   │ Since you are removing phpmyadmin, it's possible that you no longer want the underlying database.                                │ 
   │                                                                                                                                  │ 
   │ If you like, database removal can be handled with dbconfig-common.                                                               │ 
   │                                                                                                                                  │ 
   │ If you know that you do want to keep this database, or if you want to handle the removal of this database manually, you should   │ 
   │ refuse this option.                                                                                                              │ 
   │                                                                                                                                  │ 
   │ Deconfigure database for phpmyadmin with dbconfig-common?                                                                        │ 
   │                                                                                                                                  │ 
   │                                       <Yes>                                          <No>                                        │ 
   │                                                                                                                                  │ 
   └──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

with **No**.

Comment: Thanks @A.B. - that worked without error. However, I then run `sudo apt-get autoremove` and then reinstall with `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin` I get "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)".

Comment: I assume your MySQL server is running. Check the password for your MySQL user root and the access rights for this user in the `mysql.user` table. Do this on the command line with the `mysql` command.

Comment: I had a go last night but in my situation it didn't quite work - I looked up `mysql` commands and managed to fix in my case here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset